# Preserve quotation phrase string from str.replace function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In other words, I only want to replace words in the paragraph that are not inside quotation marks :

```
import sys, os.path, win32com.client 
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application') 

doc = app.Documents.Open(input_fil1) 
incontent = doc.Content.Text app.Quit() 

# want to replace what's is not inside the quote. 
otcontent = incontent.replace('No', 'Yes') 

print "New content:" print otcontent
```

Comment: Can you give us some input and expected output examples at all? What have you tried so far?

Comment: import sys, os.path, win32com.client

app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = app.Documents.Open(input_fil1)
incontent = doc.Content.Text
app.Quit()

# want to replace what's is not inside the quote.
otcontent = incontent.replace('No', 'Yes')

print "New content:"
print otcontent

# want to replace what's is not inside the quote.
otcontent = incontent.replace('No', 'Yes')

print "New content:"
print otcontent

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

Slice your text according to the quotation mark separator, and work only on the substring whose position is pair.

```
string = '''Even though "lorem ipsum" may arouse curiosity because of its resemblance to classical Latin, it is not intended to have meaning. If text is comprehensible in a document, people tend to focus on the textual content rather than upon overall presentation. Therefore publishers use lorem ipsum when displaying a typeface or design elements and page layout in order to direct the focus to the publication style and not the meaning of the text. In spite of its basis in Latin, the use of lorem ipsum is often referred to as greeking, from the phrase "it's all Greek to me", which indicates that something is not meant to be readable text (although greeking can also mean somewhat different things; see the article for details)'''

l = string.split('"')
new_l = []
for position,substring in list(enumerate(l)):
    if position%2 == 0:
        s = substring.replace('lorem','STACK OVERFLOW')
        new_l.append(s)
    else:
        new_l.append(substring)


new_string = '"'.join(new_l)

print new_string
```

Output :

```
Even though "lorem ipsum" may arouse curiosity because of its resemblance to classical Latin, it is not intended to have meaning. If text is comprehensible in a document, people tend to focus on the textual content rather than upon overall presentation. Therefore publishers use STACK OVERFLOW ipsum when displaying a typeface or design elements and page layout in order to direct the focus to the publication style and not the meaning of the text. In spite of its basis in Latin, the use of STACK OVERFLOW ipsum is often referred to as greeking, from the phrase "it's all Greek to me", which indicates that something is not meant to be readable text (although greeking can also mean somewhat different things; see the article for details)
```

The first 'lorem' is ignored since it is in a quotation.

Comment: I saved your string into file *.docx and tested with your script and works great! :) Thanks

Comment: If you find this anwser satisfying for your needs, click on the arrow on the right top corner of my answer : that way the question will be closed.